# mysql get only special data for nested set tree

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

Hope some of you mysql experts can help me.

if there is a gap in the tree then I do not want the deeper children.

**Example:**

```
root (depth 0)
sub-cat 1 (depth 1)
subsub-cat 1 (depth 2)
subsubsubsub-cat 1 (depth 4)
```

In this case a node in depth 3 is disable, i don’t need node subsubsubsub-cat 1 and deeper

**structure:**

```
id | parent_id | lft | rgt | depth | title
```

**default query:**

```
select *
from categories
where lft >= '1' and lft < '10000'
order by lft asc
```

Thanks !

Comment: A nested set exists so you don't have to check the whole path for special stuff (it will just take every node between two numbers, it doesn't care that much about gaps), so that is not (easily) possible. Just delete all children when you delete a node (this should happen anyway in a standard nested set algorithm). If you want to preserve the nodes for some reason, move them to another hidden (sub)tree or add a column and mark then as unused/hidden instead of deleting them.

Comment: Thanks, maybe is ist not possible, but i don't want delete the categories, i want to hide the children if the parent catagory disabled.
For example:
Clothes > Mens > Jeans > Slim
Don't show Slim in the tree if Jeans disabled.

Comment: How can you tell if a node is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Gaps (as in "deleted intermediate nodes", a missing `parent_id` or a jump in your `depth`-value) are hard to detect or even define in a nested set (and these columns are not needed for a nested set), but if you just want to hide a node and all its children, this can be easily done by adding a marker column to your tree, e.g. `hidden`, and only use those nodes that have no hidden predecessor (or are hidden themselves):

```
select *
from categories as node
where not exists 
  (select 1 from categories as preds
   where node.lft >= preds.lft 
         and node.rgt <= preds.rgt
         and preds.hidden = 1) 
order by node.lft;
```

Comment: One more question:
Maybe you have an idea how i get the ancestor nodes for the search result.
E.g. if i find a slim jeans in Slim,  show only the ancestors Clothes > Mens > Jeans >. 
So i have one result and show only the nodes
Clothes > Mens > Jeans > Slim.

Comment: @Tom yes, retrieving that path is a completely standard query for nested sets, have a look at e.g. [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (there will be examples to calculate the depth and the parent_id too, so you don't have to have columns for that)

Comment: I know this page very good, i don't know how i haven't seen this part not before. Thank you again!